Having trouble verifying this contract on base scan
This is a simple smart contract that utilizes the Openzeppelin ERC20 contract.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract simpleCa is ERC20 {
    address private deployer = address(0xfbB8AC489E02AC37b107cc09CaaAbAA9aEB43b6E);
    uint256 private initialSupply = 1_000_000_000_000 ether;

    constructor() ERC20("TEST", "TEST") {
        _mint(deployer, initialSupply);
    }
}


I deployed this using Remix IDE.
Then went to the verify and publish parts of the contract.
Then for the compiler type I selected Solidity (Multi-Part files).
Then I selected the version of solidity I used.
And then license type.
Then in solidity files to upload I uploaded simpleCa.sol (the code above, ERC20.sol, IERC20.sol, IERC20Metadata.sol, Context.sol, draft-IERC6093.sol).

Then when I clicked publish and verify I got the following error:
ParserError: Source "extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> ERC20.sol:7:1:
  |
7 | import {IERC20Metadata} from "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "utils/Context.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> ERC20.sol:8:1:
  |
8 | import {Context} from "../../utils/Context.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> ERC20.sol:9:1:
  |
9 | import {IERC20Errors} from "../../interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> simpleCa.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compiler debug log:

This is a very simple contract using a very well known Openzeppelin library. I have not verified a contract before so I feel as if I am making a very noob mistake as this seems like a very straight forward process.

You can refer to this answer.
Just one change if you’re using the Etherscan Plugin:
Instead of getting and saving the Etherscan API key, you need to save the BaseScan API key.
